# Accessing involved models in MorphPivot class on boot methods

Tags: laravel

I have morph many-to-many relation between Tag vs Video and Thread, I'm `using` a custom model to represent the intermediate table of my relationships, I created a model which extends `MorphPivot`, So my question is, How to get models on `boot` method ? For example:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphPivot;

class TagResource extends MorphPivot
{
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        self::created(function ($model){
            dd($model);
        });
    }
}
```

I want whenever there is a relationship between my models is created i get them with `created` event on boot method, But when i `dd($model)` in the method it just returns the table attributes of `TagResource` and not the `Tag` or `Video` model, Is there a way to get involved models instances ?

Comment: You would need to add the relationships to your `TagResource` model and then retrieve those relationships like you would with any other model.

Comment: So there is no built-in method for this ? I dont want to write more codes to get those models

Comment: This is how Laravel's relationships work unfortunately. What is it you're ultimate trying to achieve i.e. what are you planning to do in the `created()` method?

Comment: I have multiple Jobs class which dispatchs after `$video->tags()` I wanna take that jobs and paste them to the `created` method instead